# How to access external folder (Web Server)?

Tags: java, file, tomcat, web

Good Afternoon!

I have a web application: TesteWeb, which sits on a LINUX web "www.mypage123.com" server, and have a normal machine with LINUX "felipehts" I want to access the file `/home/felipehts/test.txt`, but by the command:

`File file = new File (path);`

I can not access because the "File" to access the directory server, not the client ("felipehts") that is external, how do I access the external directory serivdor ie the directory the user's machine "felipehts"??

Comment: Did I get that correctly, you want to access a file on a different machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can access any file in the server as you have explained. But the problem is you need permission to access that. The application executor should have permissions to access the files.

Read more on : [Accessing linux local file system from java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972243/accessing-linux-local-file-system-from-java-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous comment. I also suggest to consider the security issue related to accessing file system from web server.

For this particular case, you could make a link to point the file from your web server root

Comment: When I run: File file = new File (path) (local machine), the browser it does not find the path only if the path is the server. This is my question how to access the file off the server, a local machine by the browser.

Comment: Ok,I misunderstood your question. Permission problem? I guess you are using tomcat as web server, correct?

Comment: So, basically you have one server and one other Linux client on same network that hosts the file you need to reach from www server, right?

Answer (score 0):

TRY ANY ONE WAY

- 1/ first you can get the file access permission mode 777.
- 2/ ftp is the another way to access the files (you get the ftp access login credentials privately)
- 3/ get the server url credentials