# Tomcat sh script permission

Tags: java, linux, bash, tomcat, exec

I'm using Tomcat7 and i tried to launch sh script from tomcat. My sh script need to create a new file and write things in. If i launch my script like ./test.sh it's work perfectly but if i use tomcat for launch that script i go an error of permission denied during the script execution, it doesn't have the permission to write. 
This is my java code :

```
        String[] fixCmd = new String[] { path };
    Process start = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fixCmd);

    // monitor standard error to find out what's wrong
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(start.getErrorStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

and my shellScript :

```
echo test >> test.txt
```

I tried to use ProcessBuilder but it didn't worked too.

I tried to change the permission of the folder with all the solution i founds and nothing worked. When exec Tomcat used to be launching script as root so he do have all the permission required. I gived all the permission on folder to tomcat7 user in case but nothing changed. I have some other java scripts which are creating and writing file on the server so i already managed to change the right for let tomcat write things and it's work so i really don't know what is the problem of the script.

Any ideas?

Edit 1 : 
The output of `ls -l ./test.sh` done that :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat7 tomcat7 165 nov.   2 16:12 ./test.sh
```

I'm logged as root and i red tomcat is considered as root too.

Edit 2 Problem Solved : 
A specialist explained me that my problem is a security problem, as tomcat is a web server it's a security to not let it have permission on sh script for write. So i changed my approach of the problem and i will read the sh script output in java and write my file from jave.

Comment: Have you checked the execution permissions of the script itself?

Comment: Well it have all the required permissions i think, cause if i launch it in bash like ./test.sh he is doing the job perfectly.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the same user running it, is it? Tomcat runs under another user. Please do an `ls -l ./test.sh` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing files on the container's filesystem is tricky and not encouraged (imo). I guess: Your issue has nothing to do with permissions on the filesystem itself, but with permissions of the web container (here: tomcat).

See 
[Accessing linux local file system from java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972243/accessing-linux-local-file-system-from-java-web-application)

or 
[How to access external folder (Web Server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985653/how-to-access-external-folder-web-server)

Comment: Well actualy the sh script is located in my webapps  folder, so i can access it and launch it, its really just the script which seems to have no permission when it is launch from tomcat, when i launch it from bash as root it got no problem to run

Comment: you are accessing the text.txt file inside the script. Do you have proper permissions on the directory too (it needs file create permissions ie directory edit permissions) and if it exists already, on the file?

Comment: When i run from tomcat i get "cannot create test.txt: Permission denied" 
But when i run the script from shell i go no permission problem. 
text.txt have all the required permission, i just tried to chmod 777 it but its changed nothing always permissions denied.

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory, your test.sh file and test.txt file are located? ls -la.