# Java is creating file in tomcat bin folder

Tags: java, tomcat

I have written a java program in which I am creating a file.

```
BufferedWriter writer = 
    new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt"))
```

It is creating the file in the current folder (my project folder). Till here everything is perfect. Now I have designed a servlet and call this class. The file is now getting created in the tomcat bin folder. Do I need to make any changes to `classpath` or `server.xml` or `context.xml` in tomcat?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972243/accessing-linux-local-file-system-from-java-web-application

Answer (score 1):

CAUSE:

Your program is creating a new file in the "current working directory".

Since it's a servlet running inside of Tomcat, the "current directory"  happens to be Tomcat's "bin" directory.

SUGGESTIONS:

- If possible, use a fully qualified path (`"/tmp/myfile.text"`)
- You can also write your file relative to `getServletContext()`:

[How to store a file on a server(web container) through a Java EE web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663204/how-to-store-a-file-on-a-serverweb-container-through-a-java-ee-web-application)

- You can use a relative path, and parameterize either that path in a properties file  (`WEB-INF\myprog.properties`) or JVM parameter (`-D filepath=/my/file/path`).